# Result of a NMAP command in CSV file using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, nmap

I would like help writing a script in Powershell that puts in a CSV file only the nips of the nmap -sv 192.168.0.0/24 command

command output

```
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2019-11-14 17:36 E. South America Standard Time
Nmap scan report for fwmatriz.niplan.com.br (192.168.0.1)
Host is up (0.00s latency).
MAC Address: 00:1A:8C:5C:7A:9C (Sophos)
Nmap scan report for npespsql01.niplan.com.br (192.168.0.2)
Host is up (0.00s latency).
MAC Address: 80:C1:6E:62:06:00 (Hewlett Packard)
Nmap scan report for npespntpdc.niplan.com.br (192.168.0.3)
Host is up (0.00s latency).
MAC Address: 00:26:B9:4F:8A:27 (Dell)
Nmap scan report for npespdc06.niplan.com.br (192.168.0.4)
Host is up (0.00s latency).
MAC Address: D4:AE:52:70:7A:F3 (Dell)
Nmap scan report for npespntorc.niplan.com.br (192.168.0.5)
Host is up (0.00s latency).
MAC Address: 00:0C:29:F4:19:CC (VMware)
Nmap scan report for npespntfs01.niplan.com.br (192.168.0.6)
```

I would like to get a CSV file like this:

```
npespsql01
npespntpdc
npespdc06
npespntorc
npespntfs01
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like following:

```
(nmap -sv 192.168.0.0/24 | Select-String -Pattern '\S+(?=\.niplan\.com)').Matches.Value
```

You can pipe that to a file using `Set-Content` or `Out-File`. If you want to create a CSV file, you need to output an object with a named property first. Sending a collection of strings to `Export-Csv` will result in just the lengths of the strings since that is the only named property of a string object. Below is an example of creating a calculated property named `NIPS` with the values matched from the `nmap` command.

```
(nmap -sv 192.168.0.0/24 | Select-String -Pattern '\S+(?=\.niplan\.com)').Matches.Value |
    Select-Object @{Name='NIPS';Expression={$_}} |
        Export-Csv 'file.csv' -NoType
```

---

The `-Pattern` in [Select-String](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-6) uses regex pattern matching unless the `-SimpleMatch` switch is used. It may need to be tweaked in case your reverse names do not resolve to the `niplan.com.br` domain. You could do something like the following instead, which will match all characters up until the first `.` after the `Nmap scan report for` text.

```
Select-String -pattern '(?<=Nmap scan report for )[^\.]+'
```